# ESXI 5.1 - Losing access to management interface on vSwitch1 when vSwitch0 loses network access

Tags: vmware-esxi, trunk

I'm probably missing something obvious here, but, I am trying to make some adjustments to the Vkernel Port management interface on vSwitch0 that is set to VLAN ID: All (4095).

So I don't disconnect myself, I have added a second switch (vSwitch1), added the secondary NIC on my host to it and connected it to my switch.

I have connectivity to vSphere and via ping.

If I shut the port that connects vSwitch0 to my network infrastructure, my ping is maintained to my secondary vKernal Port, but I am unable to connect to vSphere...

Any tips greatly appreciated as always.

Comment: Why's it set to 4095?  And - is the management traffic checkbox checked on the second vmkernel port group?

Comment: I inherited it set as 4095, what I actually want to do is change that to be a particular VLAN then update the switch side of things to be a trunk.  That being said, I'm really worried I'm going to disconnect myself in doing so.... guess if I disconnect myself from vSphere in doing that I can always update the VLAN back to 4095 using the CLI?

Comment: Does the physical switch port that connects to the secondary physical NIC have the appropriate VLAN configured for it?

Answer (score 1):

For a change to the management vSwitch's vlan settings, it's probably easier to just make the change with the console interface.

That being said, your problem with accessing management tools is probably this checkbox in the port group settings, which defaults to off:

[image: management traffic]

Edit the port group to check that box and you should be able to connect the vSphere client against the secondary vmkernel port group.

Comment: Thanks for your input. It wasn't that the management traffic port wasn't ticked, as I was able to connect to vSphere on this IP address whilst vSwitch0 was still connected. I used the CLI to update the VLAN of the management interface on vSwitch0 and changed the cisco switch port to a trunk and I had no problems and no longer require to have two management interfaces. The question is still interesting to me but I no longer care. Thanks for your input once again.